# php array key unset if element is another element in a second array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a array named `$new_items` in the following format, with multiple items....

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 66901
        [weight] => 0.3000
        [Price] => 14.1800
        [category] => Array
            (
                [parent_id] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 222
                        [1] => 1232
                        [2] => 1315
                    )
                        ) 
                        .......and (cont...)
                            [1] => Array
    ( ......
```

I have another array `$data` in following format:

```
Array
(
[174] => 67495
[253] => 67471
[278] => 67460
[323] => 67412
[390] => 67332
[600] => 67282
[738] => 67209
)
```

I wish to remove the parent in `$new_items` array where id is present in `$data` array.

My code is as follows:

```
foreach ($new_items as $key => $item) {
if ($item['id'] === $data) {
    unset($new_items[$key]);
  }
}
```

is not removing the parent.

But if i hardcode the id as follows:

```
if ($item['id'] === "67495"),
```

It is getting removed..

Please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$data is an array, so you can't compare it with integer value! Use in_array instead..

```
foreach ($new_items as $key => $item) {
if (in_array($item['id'], $data)) {
    unset($new_items[$key]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($new_items as $key => $item) 
{

   if(array_search($item['id'], $data))
   {
       $key = array_search($item['id'], $data);
       unset($data[$key]);
   }

}
```